# Rtools can't be installed on windows under devel version of R?

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to build an R package using RStudio on Windows 8.1. When I attempt to build the package via RStudio's Build panel I receive:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
```

when I type the command in console :

```
install.packages("Rtools")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R Under development)
```

first time building R packages in Rstudio, I got confused should I used install.packages(), or directly install .exe file from CRAN. What's the right things to do to proceed package building on Rstudio ? I used devel version of R. Can any one give me quick solution on this problem ? Thanks a lot

I downloaded Rtools.exe from CRAN and installed on my machines, both tried 33, 34.exe, and restart Rstudio, but still can't build my packages, it keep saying that :

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but no version of Rtools compatible with the currently running version of R was found. Note that the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:

  - Rtools 3.3 (installed at c:\Rtools)

Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
```

Comment: Error in your assumption: There is no such package.  See the 'R Installation and Administration' manual for more.

Comment: @Jerry.Shad: that's not actually true.  Either someone misinformed you or you misinterpreted something ...

Comment: @BenBolker I installed Rtools on windows, I reopen the R session, but I still can't buildd my packages, why ? I got same error still. Any idea please?

Comment: If you're having difficulty installing Rtools on Windows (I mean, everything is kind of difficult on Windows...) you might try looking at the **installr** package, which not only is an actual package that can be installed via `install.packages("installr")`, but it might help if you're finding the normal Rtools installation process too confusing.

Comment: I gave you the advice I have to give. You can take it or not, I don't really have anything else to offer you.

Comment: you said you tried to install Rtools version 3.4 (Rtools34), but I would try it again. Your installation message above suggests you're using R 3.4 (i.e. development), which is *not* compatible with Rtools33, according to the CRAN Rtools page, and the error message says you have Rtools33 installed ...

Comment: @BenBolker I set up the path, now it worked. Thanks again for your concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download from here and install like a software.
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: I installed Rtools, but still can't build my packages ? why is that ?

Comment: Did you restart the R?

Comment: Perhaps it is a path issue.  R cannot detect the Rtools on your computer.

Comment: I guess so. how can I configure the path ?

Comment: First, check where is your Rtools.  Maybe C://Rtools?, Then follow standard steps like in http://www.howtogeek.com/51807/how-to-create-and-use-global-system-environment-variables/ to set the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129476/discussion-between-kota-mori-and-jerry-shad).

Comment: This page seems helpful. https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Install-Rtools-for-Windows